# flatpickr typescript error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: angular, typescript, travis-ci, flatpickr

I am using flatpickr with angular 5.0 app.

In my file i have imported flatpickr as below

```
import * as flatpickerNamespace from 'flatpickr';
const flatpickr = (flatpickerNamespace as any).default;
const fp = flatpickr(this.dateInput.nativeElement, {
  allowInput: true,
  dateFormat: 'm/d/Y',
  nextArrow: this.rightArrowHTML(),
  prevArrow: this.leftArrowHTML(),
  onClose: (selectedDates) => {
    this.updateClassNames(this.calendar);
    this.dateInput.nativeElement.classList.remove('bx--focused');
  },
  onChange: () => {
    this.updateClassNames(this.calendar);
    this.dateInput.nativeElement.classList.remove('bx--focused');
  },
  onMonthChange: () => {
    this.updateClassNames(this.calendar);
  },
  onYearChange: () => {
    this.updateClassNames(this.calendar);
  },
  onOpen: () => {
    this.updateClassNames(this.calendar);
  },
});
```

This code works perfectly in the local machine and getting built with 'ng build --prod' command. but I am getting the below error in Travis build:

> ERROR in node_modules/@cloudMatrix-CAM/cb-carbon-angular-components/src/date-picker-single/date-picker-single.component.ts(198,16): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof "/home/travis/build/cloudMatrix-CAM/cb-shared-components-ui/node_modules/flatpickr/dist/ty...' has no compatible call signatures.

I have tried all possible ways to fix this. but nothing works!. any ideas on how to resolve this issue.